# make Error -1073741502 building for ATmega in Eclipse

Tags: ide, embedded, eclipse-cdt, toolchain

```
02:55:44 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project MASTER ( SPI ) ****
make all 
Building file: ../SPI-PROG.c
Invoking: AVR Compiler
avr-gcc -Wall -g2 -gstabs -O0 -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -mmcu=atmega32 -DF_CPU=16000000UL -MMD -MP -MF"SPI-PROG.d" -MT"SPI-PROG.o" -c -o "SPI-PROG.o" "../SPI-PROG.c"
make: *** [SPI-PROG.o] Error -1073741502

02:55:46 Build Finished (took 2s.127ms)
```

[image]

Comment: It means that Eclipse is broken crap still. Consider getting a better IDE, this is the worst one ever made by mankind, all categories.

Comment: @Abdelrahman Windows Vista!?  There's another problem right there.  If you have solved your question, either post an answer ( not a comment) or delete the question if it has no community value (it does not - it was an installation error probably unique to you).  That will prevent others wasting Thier time on this.

Comment: you need to replace the msys-1.0.dll file in the C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin with newer version

Answer (score 0):

avr-gcc.exe has failed to start.  Most likely your WinAVR toolchain install is bad.

Run

```
avr-gcc --version
```

directly from the command-line to check if it can run.  If it does, it is perhaps an issue with how Eclipse is configured.